# SQL RANK but higher if equal?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, count, window-functions

For data:

```
20
50
50
60
70
```

If I use RANK I get

```
1
2
2
4
5
```

if I use DENSE_RANK I get

```
1
2
2
3
4
```

I need for my application this:

```
1
3
3
4
5
```

Comment: What do you mean by “higher”? +1 only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
rank() over(order by val) + count(*) over(partition by val) - 1
```

Actually this would be simpler phrased with just a window count:

```
count(*) over(order by val)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=100de100138a32d2728c2f9edb046fc7)**:

```
select val, count(*) over(order by val) rn
from (values (20), (50), (50), (60), (70)) as t(val)
order by val
```

```
val | rn
--: | -:
 20 |  1
 50 |  3
 50 |  3
 60 |  4
 70 |  5
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first one because in my case (I forgot to mention) I used DESC order and the second option won't work with that (I can count all the rows and do LENGTH - rn +1 to get what I want but It's not as neat)